Twilio Server Rings "to" Number, Then Hangs Up?
I am setting up Twilio Voice Calling.  I have this code on my client:
function makeCall() {
    if (!window.twilioDevice) {
        console.error('Twilio Device not ready');
        return;
    }

    const params = {
        to: '+1555#######',
        from: '+1555#######'
    };

    const connection = window.twilioDevice.connect(params);
}

On my server I have:
WebApp.handlers.use('/twilio_voice', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const accountSid = Meteor.settings.twilio.accountSid;
        const authToken = Meteor.settings.twilio.authToken;
        const twilioClient = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

        const to = '+1##########'
        const from = '+1##########'
        // const { to, from } = req.body; // Ensure your client sends these in the request body

        if (!to || !from) {
            let errorMsg = `twilio_voice endpoint: Missing "to" or "from" phone number. to: ${to} from: ${from}`
            console.log(errorMsg);
            res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: errorMsg }));
            return;
        }

        const call = await twilioClient.calls.create({
            twiml: '<Response><Say>Hello, this is a call from a user. User, please go ahead and say hello.</Say></Response>',
            to: to,
            from: from
        });

        console.log('Call SID: ', call.sid);
        res.type('application/json');
        res.send({ success: true, callSid: call.sid });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in /twilio_voice:', error);
        res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: error.message }));
    }
});

On the client, a voice says "Sorry, an application error has occurred. Goodbye."
On the "to" cell phone, the phone rings, and it speaks the TwiML text - then hangs up.
What am I leaving out?

Have you checked the error logs? It would be helpful if you could add some details that are mentioned there as well.

I found complete working source code provided by Twilio at this link:
https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node
